# Timeout error when calling an cloud functions api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-functions, apigee

I have an API as a google cloud function, which needs for the output like 40 seconds. Now I want to implement it as an apigee proxy but whenever I call it from a proxy, it returns the following error after 30 seconds:

*"upstream request timeout"*

I think the default timeout-time is 30 seconds and that's likely the problem. I tried different methods like parsing the following xml parts to solve the problem, but it didn't work:

```xml
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>https://mocktarget.apigee.net/json</URL> 
    <Properties>
      <Property name="io.timeout.millis">120000</Property>
    </Properties>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

Or

```xml
<TargetEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPTargetConnection>
    <URL>https://mocktarget.apigee.net/json</URL>
    <Properties>
      <Property name="connect.timeout.millis">5000</Property>
    </Properties>
  </HTTPTargetConnection>
</TargetEndpoint>
```

also didn't work. Here are the docs: https://docs.apigee.com/how-to-guides/configuring-connect-timeout-on-message-processors?hl=de

I also didn't found preferences for timeout stuff on Apigee.

I hope you guys can help me here, thank you in advance! :)

Comment: What is the returned HTTP error? None of the default timeouts are 30 seconds.

Comment: The Error Code is "504 Gateway Timeout". Apigee docu says "If a timeout happens while reading the HTTP response, 504, Gateway Timeout is returned." So I guess, it's the timeout here: https://docs.apigee.com/api-platform/reference/endpoint-properties-reference. So basically if I'm reducing the response time to under 30 seconds, it works..
@JohnHanley

Comment: Just check where the timeout is happening. THere is no 30 sec default timeout at APIGEE layer. It can be timing out at the network layer as well if you organization uses any.